# sed + add remark before string in specific line

Tags: sed

My target is to add remark "#" before the "dialog" string 
only in line that has the "Restart nfs and apply changes" line

Why my sed command not add the "#" char before the dialog string? , what wrong? In my syntax?

```
       sed -i -r '/Restart nfs and apply changes/s/dialog ?$/#dialog/'  /etc/init.d/nfsscript.sh
```

the line in /etc/init.d/nfsscript.sh file :

```
      dialog  --clear --colors --title "nfs Config" --yesno "Restart nfs and apply changes?" 10 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
sed -e '/Restart nfs and apply changes/s/dialog/\#dialog/' -i /etc/init.d/nfsscript.sh
```

Comment: `s/dialog/\#dialog/` can be simplified to `s/dialog/\#&/`